# Preparing Python Tuple for SQL Statement

Tags: python, postgresql, tuples

Error on SQL Statement, what is the best way to prepare a tuple for SQL Statement. I want to avoid "('".

```
F = tuple(E)

statement = "select * from x.({0})".format(
    ', '.join(['%s'] * len(F)))
G = cur.execute(statement, F)
G = sqlio.read_sql_query(G, conn)
print(G)
```

Got an Error like this:

```
SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: select * from x.(' <<<
```

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `x.{}` without `()`?

Comment: Actually, I think `x` should be in the join. It's not clear to me what this is supposed to do. Why format in `%s` when you can't parameterize table names or column names?

Comment: It would help if the OP would show what the SQL statement should look like.

Comment: Actaully I want to have an SQL-Statement + variable from tuples. The Tuples inculde the table names.

Comment: Ok, but I already said that you can't parameterize table names

Comment: "select * from x." + tablename in tuple - like this?

Comment: Is it possible to use concate to solve the problem?

Comment: What library are you using to get `cur`? `psycopg2`, for example, provides a way to safely build dynamic SQL queries.

Comment: You told us what you want to achieve, but please give us an example how the resulting sql statement should look like. I have a feeling that your knowledge of SQL is limited and that you try to do the wrong thing.

Comment: I want all tables from the DB and I have got a list of tables I want to request.
Result should be a table.